# How to import native node module (node-gyp) in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-gyp

In JavaScript it work
But in typescript **'module not found'**

```js
const addon = require('../build/Debug/addon')

console.log(addon.helloworld()) //Hello World
```

I try this three syntax

```js
import * as addon from '..../build/Debug/addon'

// Also 
import * as addon from '..../build/Debug/addon.node'

// Also
import addon = require('..../build/Debug/addon')
```

Typescript compile to

```js
module.exports = ..../build/Debug/addon
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "allowJs": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: tsconfig.json `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "allowJs": true,

  },
}`